# How to use require.js for managing JavaScript dependencies in a Django project?

Tags: javascript, django, requirejs, django-staticfiles, r.js

I use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) for managing dependencies between my JavaScript libraries and modules. The backend is written in Django. Django has many [apps for managing static assets](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/asset-managers/), but none of them talk about incorporating the [r.js compiler](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js).

**What's the best way to manage and compile my JS files using r.js in Django?**

My requirements are:

1. Versioned output file to get around caching when the file is updated.
2. Automatically use uncompiled JS file when `DEBUG = True` in `settings.py` for Django, and the compiled file when `Debug = False`.
3. Some of the libraries will be loaded from CDN (such jquery) with a local fallback.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Interesting timing. I just finished writing a `r.js` module for `django-assets`. Needs some polish and I should be able to open source it.

Comment: Awesome! If you need a beta tester, count me in!

Comment: For the caching part, I copy the JQuery Ajax NoCache method (somewhat), by adding a version number to the request src='/path/to/file.js?VERSION={{ settings.VERSION }}'

Comment: @Pykler Do you update `settings.VERSION` manually every time you edit one of the JS files, or do you have that automated somehow?

Comment: @WyattAnderson Any progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems as though django-require covers at least some of what you need,  https://github.com/etianen/django-require .